# Repurchase count with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have such table:

```
Date       Buyer_id
11.11.2016  1
11.11.2016  2
11.11.2016  2
13.12.2016  1
13.12.2016  3
13.12.2016  4
14.12.2016  3
14.12.2016  1
```

I need to calculate in pandas Repurchase number
So i need number of people who visited shop in **different** days (it's important).
So buyers #1,3 are good, buyer #2,4 are bad.

result should be:
good_buyers = 2
bad_buers = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would yield the result you want:

```
s = (df.groupby('Buyer_id')['Date']
         .apply(lambda x: 'Good' if len(x.unique()) > 1 else 'Bad')
         .value_counts())
print(s)
```

Output:

```
Good    2
Bad     2
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

If you need a dictionary of the result:

```
d = s.to_dict()
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'Bad': 2, 'Good': 2}
```